# Custom xcframework not working rosetta simulator, But working in real device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcframework

After the failure of universal framekwork with lipo. i created .xcframework. This is my structure of framework :

CustomFramework.xcframework

- Info.plist
- ios-arm64
- ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator

This framework is working fine in real device. But when i try to run on rosetta simulator i am getting this below error :

> Unsupported Swift architecture
> Could not build Objective-C module 'mylibraryname'

But when i delete ios-arm64 folder from my CustomFramework.xcframework, i was able to run on my rosetta simulator.

I choosed rosetta simulator from

> Product > Destination > Destination architecture > show rosetta simulator/show both

For running on device i need to again add this ios-arm64 folder in to my CustomFramework.xcframework.

Client dont need two release builds, they need it in one go which should work in both simulator ( rosetta ) and release device.

My run script to generate .xcframework :

> Type a script or drag a script file from your workspace to insert its path.
> #Gerenate device framework
> xcodebuild archive -scheme ${PROJECT_NAME} -archivePath "${PROJECT_DIR}/build/${PROJECT_NAME}-iphoneos.xcarchive" -sdk iphoneos SKIP_INSTALL=NO BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES
>
> #Generate simulator framework
> xcodebuild archive -scheme ${PROJECT_NAME} -archivePath "${PROJECT_DIR}/build/${PROJECT_NAME}-iossimulator.xcarchive" -sdk iphonesimulator SKIP_INSTALL=NO BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES
>
> #Generate xcframework for both arches
> xcodebuild -create-xcframework -framework "${PROJECT_DIR}/build/${PROJECT_NAME}-iphoneos.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" -framework "${PROJECT_DIR}/build/${PROJECT_NAME}-iossimulator.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" -output "${PROJECT_DIR}/build/${PROJECT_NAME}.xcframework"
>
> #Open directory where xcframework were generate
> open "${PROJECT_DIR}/build"

Swift version, deployment versions are all same only. But still above one not wokring when both slice present in same framework. i tried adding the exclude architecture like belwo :

Exclude Architecture

- Debug

  - Any iOS simulator  = arm64
  - Any iOS SDK = x86_64

but still no luck. i need to delete the ios-arm64 folder in to my CustomFramework.xcframework to make it run on rosetta simulator.
And re-add again to run on real device.

---